# Firebase RecyclerView Image not showing, rest of the information is

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, firebaseui

On my activity class the RecyclerView is successfully retrieving information in TextView from Firebase and displaying it, however Image View is not showing the image as desired using Picasso.

I've already tried using Piccaso.get().load("image").into() but it still doesn't show the image.

The class for the activity also containing the view holder is:

```
public class BeefSamosa extends AppCompatActivity {


   private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataHome, DataHomeViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beef_samosa);
        //Back Button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Beef Samosa");


        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.beef_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = rootRef.child("DataHome");

        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<DataHome> firebaseRecyclerOptions = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<DataHome>()
                .setQuery(query, DataHome.class)
                .build();


        firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<DataHome, DataHomeViewHolder>(firebaseRecyclerOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DataHomeViewHolder dataHomeViewHolder, int position, @NonNull DataHome dataHome) {
                dataHomeViewHolder.setDataHome(dataHome);
            }

            @Override
            public DataHomeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.homedetail, parent, false);

                return new DataHomeViewHolder(view);
            }
        };
        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (firebaseRecyclerAdapter!= null) {
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.stopListening();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == android.R.id.home){
            //ends the activity
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }





    //DataHomeViewHolder class

    private class DataHomeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView  titletext, description, ingredients, directions;
        private ImageView imagetoo;


        DataHomeViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            imagetoo = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imagetoo);
            titletext = itemView.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
            description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            ingredients = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ingredients);
            directions = itemView.findViewById(R.id.directions);
        }


        void setDataHome(DataHome DataHome) {
            Picasso.get().load("image").into(imagetoo);
            String titleto = DataHome.getTitle();
            titletext.setText(titleto);
            String descriptionto = DataHome.getDescription();
            description.setText(descriptionto);
            String ingredientsto = DataHome.getIngredients();
            ingredients.setText(ingredientsto);
            String directionsto = DataHome.getDirections();
            directions.setText(directionsto);
        }
    }
}
```

The xml file is:

```
<ScrollView

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
tools:context=".Fragments.Home"
android:orientation="vertical"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"

android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >


        <!-- Image -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="140dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imagetoo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />



        <!-- Title-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titletext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:scaleType="fitStart" />


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="250dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />

        <!-- Description   -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:text="Description:"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />

        <!-- Ingredients -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:text="Ingredients:"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ingredients"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="21sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />

        <!-- Directions -->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:text="Directions:"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/directions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />


    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

The other class is:

public class DataHome {

```
public DataHome() {}

public String title ,image, description, ingredients, directions;

public DataHome(String title, String image, String description, String ingredients, String directions){
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.description = description;
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.directions= directions;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}


public String getIngredients() {
    return ingredients;
}


public String getDirections() {
    return directions;
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.load()` expects url of your image. Change this line

```
Picasso.get().load("image").into(imagetoo);
```

to

```
Picasso.get().load(DataHome.getImage()).into(imagetoo);
```